# Forcing the location of a list

Tags: beamer, spacing

I would like a Beamer slide to consist of a list of questions and answers, but I do not want to expose them all at once. I would like the first exposure to display the first question. The second exposure displays the first question and the first answer. The third exposure shows the first question, first answer, second question, and so on. Easy enough.

It would be nice if this list always started at the same vertical location, so that visually the earlier Qs and As remain fixed as the list grows, but I cannot find a way to force this.

ADDITION This was my first effort

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
{\LARGE
\begin{frame}{\huge List of Questions}
\vspace*{-1in}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is the first question.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\huge List of Questions}
\vspace*{-1in}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is the first question.
\item This is the first answer.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\huge List of Questions}
\vspace*{-1in}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is the first question.
\item This is the first answer.
\item This is the second question
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\huge List of Questions}\vspace*{-1in}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is the first question.
\item This is the first answer.
\item This is the second question.
\item This is the second answer.

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a small, but compilable test document which shows us what kind of list you use. If you uncover them items, they should stay at the same position.

Answer (score 1):

Beamer items are overlay aware (see section "3.10 Using Overlay Specifications" in the beamer user guide). This means that you can use e.g. `\item<3-> second question` to specify on which overlay within the frame the item should be revealed.

If you are revealing the items one by one, beamer can even do this automatically for you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\huge}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Questions}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item This is the first question.
\item This is the first answer.
\item This is the second question.
\item This is the second answer.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i should have looked beyond quick guides.

Comment: @PhilipRoe You're welcome! Have fun with beamer!